# classifying tweets if fitness related or not

Tags: classification, text-classification, tweets

For a school project we have to find out if a tweet is related to fitness / physical activity or not. The whole dataset contains 50 million unlabeled tweets.

What are possible classifications for this undertaking?

Comment: This seems far too broad a question; what techniques are you supposed to use - simple text matching, semantic analysis, Deep Learning, or other?

Comment: it doesn't matter which technique we use! it just has to be something more advanced then just writing a dictionary and checking if the words of the dictionary appear in the tweet or not.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be with some sort of artificial intelligence.

One of the most popular frameworks out there is [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) by Google. I assume if you are doing this for school you have some experience with AIs anyway...

If you need some help getting started there is a very good YouTube tutorial series that is great for beginners which you can find [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cKxRvEZd3Mw).

Good luck!

Comment: @KenY-N Fair enough, I have changed my wording to reflect that.